# How would one prove this flavour of the triangle inequality?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers

I have to prove $|z_1 - z_2| \leq |z_1|+|z_2|$ where $z_1,z_2$ are in $\mathbb{C}$. What I wrote down is:

$$|z_1| = |z_1+z_2-z_2| \geq |z_1-z_2|-|z_2|\implies |z_1|+|z_2|\geq |z_1-z_2|,$$as desired.  Is this correct, or am I making assumptions I shouldn't be making?

Comment: Well, that's a bit weird. As you are using the triangle inequality, why not just use $|z_1-z_2| = |z_1 + (-z_2)| \leq |z_1| + |-z_2| = |z_1| + |z_2|$ ?

Comment: Can you assume the usual triangle inequality? If so, you're making it too difficult:
$$
|z_1-z_2|=|z_1+(-z_2)|\leq|z_1|+|-z_2|\cdots
$$

Comment: Geez, you guys are right. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the proof by Rudin (if $x, y \in  \mathbb R^2$, then $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$):
$$|x+y|^2 = (x+y)(x+y) = x \cdot x + 2 x \cdot y + y \cdot y \le |x|^2 + 2|x||y| + |y|^2 = (|x|+|y|)^2$$

The inequality $|xy| \le |x| |y|$ is a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: The OP is clearly asking for the case $x,y\in\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: I hope that the proof for simpler case, where $x, y$ are both real, will help the OP to prove it for complex number. A hint would be to use the complex conjugation...

Comment: As was pointed out in the comments of the question, this is simply a special case of the usual complex triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

This may give a more satisfactory answer to the OP's question, albeit the problem statement is *mildly* different.

**Problem:** If $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are complex, prove that
$$
|z_1+\cdots+z_n| \leq |z_1|+\cdots+|z_n|.
$$
*Solution.* We proceed by induction on $n$. For $n=1$, there is nothing to show and the case $n=2$ is the triangle inequality which is given by Theorem 1.33 (e) on page 14 in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

---

**Theorem 1.33 (e):** Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers. Then
$$
|z+w| \leq |z|+|w|.
$$
*Proof.* Note that $\overline{z}w$ is the conjugate of $z\overline{w}$, so that $z\overline{w}+\overline{z}w = 2 \;\mathrm{Re}\;(z\overline{w})$. Hence
\begin{align}
|z+w|^2 &= (z+w)(\overline{z}+\overline{w})\\
        &=z\overline{z}+z\overline{w}+\overline{z}w+w\overline{w}\\
        &= |z|^2+ 2\;\mathrm{Re}\;(z\overline{w})+|w|^2\\
        &\leq |z|^2 + 2|z\overline{w}|+|w|^2\\
        &= |z|^2+2|z||w|+|w|^2\\
        &= (|z|+|w|)^2.
\end{align}
Thus, the result follows by taking square roots.

---

Returning to the proof of the original proposition, suppose the result holds for $n-1$. Then
\begin{align}
|z_1+\cdots+z_n| &= |z_1+(z_2+\cdots+z_n)|\\
                 &\leq |z_1|+|z_2+\cdots+z_n|\\
                 &= |z_1|+|z_2|+\cdots+|z_n|,
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows by the inductive hypothesis applied to the term $|z_2+\cdots+z_n|$.